# I keep getting an odd output when adding rational numbers

Tags: object, addition

I'm taking my first java class and we have to add,multiply, divide and subtract rational numbers. but for some reason I keep getting an odd output for my code

```
public class RatNums {
public static void main (String[] args){

    numbers num1;
    numbers num2;
    num1=new numbers(15,6);       //numerator and denominator
    num2=new numbers(7,8);

System.out.println(num1.add(num2)); 


  }

}


class numbers{
private double numer,denumi;
public numbers(double num,double denum){                  //constructor
numer=num;
denumi=denum;
      }

public numbers add(numbers obj){    //The add method
    return new numbers((numer * obj.denumi) + (obj.numer*denumi),(denumi*obj.denumi)+(obj.denumi*denumi));

  }
}
```

numbers@2e6e1408

This is the output I get, any ideas?

Comment: you need to implement a toString() method in your numbers class

Comment: How do I implement it with this?